# Does a pulsed (spiking) neural network outperform a recurrent neural net?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network

Both pulsed and recurrent neural networks can model time varying information.  But I am not sure which model is better relative to the computational cost.  Does it pay to use the more complex pusled neural network or will the recurrent neural net work just as well with a lot less calculation required?  Does a pulsed net converge more quickly?

Thanks

Comment: Could you say more about what you're trying to model?

Comment: I am trying to replicate the place cells that identify if the stream of images being viewed is novel or familiar and classify on a 2D map where it thinks it is and what direction it is facing.  There are also a number of other time varying signals such as audio processing and motion planning that would benefit from a temporal model of pattern recognition.

Comment: What platforms have you used to model these phenomena before?

Comment: Since I can't get the bounty back, if you want to answer it for yourself go ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you are looking at the problem the right way. The most important property of a neural network (or any predictive model) is it's accuracy. I would rather spend 10 times longer building the model, if it were significantly more accurate (and predictive).

There are many standard techniques for assessing the predictive power of your model, such as
* leave-one-out cross validation
* leave-many-out cross validation
* Fisher randomization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Fisher)

There are also many guiding principles for building a predictive model, such as
* occam's razor
* avoid overfitting (http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~tgd/classes/534/slides/part10.pdf)
* penalties for overfitting  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics))

Here are a few places to look for more information
http://predictivemodelingblog.blogspot.com/
http://www.statsoft.com/textbook/data-mining-techniques/

Bottom line: go for the simplest model that can explain your data

Answer (score 0):

Let me take a stab at answering the original question, which was specific to the performance of spiking neural nets. I've only recently begun to familiarize myself with spiking nets, but to date the best commentary I've found on their performance is Hélène Paugam-Moisy and Sander Bohte's monograph "Computing with Spiking Neuron Networks," which is available without a paywall [here](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~sbohte/publication/paugam_moisy_bohte_SNNChapter.pdf) and other sites.

From this source, it appears that in general, they perform well in the sense of their innate capabilities; spiking networks are universal approximators and like some of their kin among ordinary neural nets, their "computational power outperforms a Turing machine." (p. 5, Paugam-Moisy and Bohte). In fact, for Type-B spiking neurons, Wolfgang Maass "concludes that spiking neuron networks are computationally more powerful than both the 1st and the 2nd generations of neural networks," i.e. the perceptron family and the class of nets with continuous activations (p. 21, Paugam-Moisy and Bohte). On the other hand, they're prone to the Loading Problem, which can be NP-Complete under certain conditions discussed in the paper.

In terms of computational performance, the sundry subtypes of spiking nets vary wildly in their resources demands. On pp. 12, 14-15 Paugam-Moisy and Bohte give a nice, quick summary of some of the differences in processing operations:

> "The Hodgkin-Huxley model (HH) is realistic but far too much complex
>   for the simulation of SNNs. Although ODE9 solvers can be applied
>   directly to the system of differential equations, it would be
>   intractable to compute temporal interactions between neurons in a
>   large network of Hodgkin-Huxley models."
>
> "...The complexity range can also be expressed in terms of the
>   computational requirements for simulation. Since it is defined by four
>   differential equations, the Hodgkin-Huxley model requires about 1200
>   floating point computations (FLOPS) per 1ms simulation. Simplified to
>   two differential equations, the Morris-LeCar or FitzHugh-Nagumo models
>   have still a computational cost of one to several hundreds FLOPS. Only
>   5 FLOPS are required by the LIF model, around 10 FLOPS for variants
>   such as LIF-with-adaptation and quadratic or exponential
>   Integrate-and- Fire neurons, and around 13 FLOPS for Izhikevich’s
>   model."

As expected, there's a tradeoff between computational capabilities and these computing costs; LIF may require few FLOPS, but later in the article they detail how it is not capable of achieving the accuracy that other spiking enjoy. The computational requirements will also be dramatically affected by the manner in which spiking nets are coded (which I intend to do myself, but have not yet had a chance to experiment with yet). On pp. 38-39 Paugam-Moisy and Bohte strongly recommend using an event-driven architecture that can leverage parallelism to the utmost. I'd also recommend checking out their extensive bibliography, which I'm sure can lead to dozens of other practical performance tips. I hope that helps.